# Construction of an NFA knowing only the equivalence classes and some examples of L

Tags: automata, finite-automata

> For a certain language $L \subseteq \{a, b\}^∗$, IL has exactly four equivalence
>   classes. They are $[\lambda]$, $[a]$, $[ab]$, and $[b]$. It is also true that the three
>   strings $a$, $aa$, and $abb$ are all equivalent, and that the two strings $b$ and
>   $aba$ are equivalent. Finally, $ab \in L$, but $\lambda$ and $a$ are not in $L$, and $b$ is
>   not even a prefix of any element of $L$. Draw an FA accepting $L$

How would I draw a finite automaton for this I know there four states a, ab, b, and empty set.

Comment: What is IL? What is the language $L$? Is the task to infer $L$ with only the information given, or did you leave out information? Anyway, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am not sure what L is except that it is subset of {a,b}*

Answer (score 1):

From any class $[x]$ move to $[xa]$ using letter $a$, and similarly to $[xb]$ with letter $b$.

So, from $[\lambda]$ we move to $[a]$ with letter $a$, and from there to $[aa]$ with another $a$. As $a$ and $aa$ are equivalent, in fact state $[a]$ equals state $[aa]$.

As $a$ is not in $L$, $[a]$ can not be a final/accepting state.

Etcetera.

Comment: I still dont get it...

Comment: Sorry. Try to find explanations on the [Myhill-Nerode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) theory of regular languages. in your textbook or reader.